# Would I be able to separate variables into another class but keep the usage the same?

Tags: python

I'm trying to rewrite a script and I'm stuck on making it easy to use. Basically it's an assembly script (like the reverse of destruction), where you input a load of variables such as location, whether the location is absolute or relative, scale, rotation, visibility, random offset, etc, to create an animation. The first version was very non user friendly, so I'm trying to get it working nicely from the start this time.

I've thought of how I'd like it to work, and I've managed to keep it clean, but there is a flaw. As you can see below, it'd be possible to use anything like `SetGroup.frame[i].save()`, which I don't want (and I don't want to put checks on `if name is None` throughout the class).

Here is the code I have:

```
class SetGroup(object):

    def __init__(self, name=None, _frame_only=False):

        if name is None and not _frame_only:
            raise TypeError('name of group must be provided')

        self.selection = None
        self.origin = None

        self.start = None
        self.end = None
        self.offset = 0
        self.distance = None
        self.random = 0

        self.location = None
        self.rotation = None
        self.scale = None
        self.visibility = None

        if not _frame_only:
            self.frame = defaultdict(lambda: SetGroup(_frame_only=True))

    def save(self):
        self.load()
        #do a bit of error checking here
        self.data[self.name] = {'ObjectSelection': self.selection,
                                'ObjectOrigin': self.origin,
                                'FrameStart': self.start,
                                'FrameEnd': self.end,
                                'FrameOffset': self.offset,
                                'FrameDistance': self.distance,
                                'FrameRandom': self.random,
                                'StartLocation': self.location,
                                'StartRotation': self.rotation,
                                'StartScale': self.scale,
                                'StartVisibility': self.visibility,
                                'ExtraFrames': self.frame}
        pm.fileInfo['AssemblyScript'] = StoreData().save(self.data)

    def load(self):
        try:
            self.data = StoreData().load(pm.fileInfo['AssemblyScript'])
        except KeyError:
            pm.fileInfo['AssemblyScript'] = StoreData().save({})
```

The way I'd like it to work is like this:

```
a = SetGroup('test')
a.location = ((0, 0, 0), True)
a.start = 0
a.end = 10
a.frame[5].location = ((10, 10, 10), False)
a.frame[5].scale = ((2, 1, 1), True)
a.save()
```

Unless anyone can think of a way which would make it more friendly to use, how would I separate `location`, `rotation`, `scale`, and `visibility` into another class and link them up again, so that they still work at the core level of the class, but also work for the frame dictionary too?

Edit - Got it working to a basic level:

```
class _MovementInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, location=None, rotation=None, scale=None, visibility=None):
        self.location = location
        self.rotation = rotation
        self.scale = scale
        self.visibility = visibility

    def __repr__(self):
        return '_MovementInfo(location={x.location}, rotation={x.rotation}, scale={x.scale}, visibility={x.visibility}'.format(x=self)
```

Then I used this in the main class to merge the dictionaries:

```
self.__dict__.update({k: v for k, v in _MovementInfo().__dict__.iteritems() if '__' not in k})
self.frame = defaultdict(_MovementInfo)
```

Comment: are you familiar with the subclass concept? you can write a class with all the basic behavior you want and make a subclass from it with any extra behavior you want and that will also have the original one.

Comment: I've seen people use `super`, but never quite got my head around it. I managed to get something working since I remembered that `__dict__` contains all the values, I'll update the question with it in case anyone has a better way :)

Comment: Did you miss a line when pasting the original code? You never assign self.name in the initializer.

Comment: Ah yeah good spot, the save and load functions are remnants of an older class so I hadn't tested them yet :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the code like this:

```py
class SetGroup(_Movement):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        if name is None:
            # ...
        super().__init__()
        # ...
        self.random = 0  # __init__ should end here

    # ...
```

But you should check that all `_MovementInfo`'s in all frames are `_MovementInfo`'s or have inherited from them (to check this: `isinstance(x, _MovementInfo)`), but are not `SetGroup`'s (to check this: `not isinstance(x, SetGroup)`).

`super()` is short for `super(SetGroup, self)` (you have to use the last option for python2), and is basicly an object that holds all things that the base class has, and allows you to call methods that modify the class calling it.

Or in code:

```py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.x = 2
        self.y = y

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, y, z):
        super().__init__(y)  # equivalent to: A.__init__(self, y)
        self.z = z

b = B(3, 4)
# b's x is 2, b's y is 3 (both set by A.__init__, the last one was passed by B), and b's z is 4 (set by B.__init__)
```

I hope this helped,

CodenameLambda

Comment: Ah thanks, so with this, do I keep `self.frame = defaultdict(_MovementInfo)` and lose the `self.__dict__.update` part?

Comment: I kinda get the idea now with your updated question, however it's complaining I can't have `super()` with no arguments (same error if I copy and paste your 2nd example). I saw online that maybe `super(_MovementInfo, self)` would work, but it didn't :P

Comment: Yep. that is basicly what you should do. Because the `__dict__` thing is done by inheriting, and the frames are just a dictionary containing `_MovementInfo`'s.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it, in terms of the 2nd example, I'd understood it slightly wrong and was using `super(A, self)` instead of `super(B, self)`. Thanks a bunch for the help, I now understand the basics of how it works :)    Just seems a bit odd that the Python 2 way needs to be given what should be obvious values

Comment: That is why it was changed in Python3 (but is still possible, you can have a lot of fun with super ^^)